# Angular2 Universal deploy to apache remote server

Tags: angular, apache, .htaccess, deployment, angular-universal

I'm having problem when deploying my web application to Apache remote server.
I've achieved deploying a standard Angular2 web application which use a RESTful API service (written in PHP, hosted at /public_html/api) by these steps:

1. Open command line at project directory, run `ng build --prod`
2. Copy everything inside dist/ directory into remote server
   /public_html/
3. Copy `.htaccess` file from [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers) to the same location on remote server
4. Web application and getting data from RESTful API work

However, I need to integrate Angular2 Universal into project, so I followed the instructions in [Angular Sever Side Rendering](https://angular.io/guide/universal) and this [GitHub wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering). But after all, I only can integrate and run universal project on my local machine with port 4000, as the tutorial shown. I don't know how to properly deploy it to Apache remote server and config `.htaccess` file. Theses are steps I took but didn't work as I expected:

1. On my local machine, run `npm build...` to create dist/ folder which
   has browser/ and server/ folder and `server.js` file
2. Copy whole dist/ folder to /public_html/
3. Using Putty, SSH to remote server and at public_html directory, I
   run `node dist/server.js`
4. I got log "Node server listening on http://localhost:4000"
5. Then, I go to my browser and type in http://my_server_ip:4000 but
   surely nothing show up. The browser keep loading and when I open console F12 on Firefox there are no error or any log show.

I need to integrate Angular2 Universal Server Side Rendering because Google crawler cannot index my web project, it's only load data when real user go into website. Please help, thank you!

Comment: When you say nothing shows up, what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error message in the browser's console? Did you check the logs server side? Does your request even reach the website?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the browser keep loading or maybe trying to connect to server port, there're no error or log come up in console nor server side. I'm not sure if the request reached server because I forgot to check the Network console.

Comment: Is it not a firewall problem? is port 4000 opened on the server? Normally, you are mean to access apache (port 80), which will proxy the request to nodejs on port 4000

Comment: Hi, I've checked on my Apache server and port 4000 wasn't listening, even after run `node dist/server.js` the console return with "Node server listening on http://localhost:4000". I don't know if steps I took was the right way to deploy Angular2 Universal project.

Comment: Hi @David, I think I found the answer here (don't know it didn't show up first time I search) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47120385/how-to-properly-launch-angular-universal-to-live-server. I guess this question can be closed now, thank you.